# Gradient on a Rectangle's Border in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

This Question I have seems to be quite common for other languages and frameworks:

How do you apply a gradient on a rectangle's border?
My solution so far is a custom component such as:

```
Item {
    id: root
    property int borderWidth
    property alias borderGradient: border.gradient
    property alias gradient: fill.gradient
    property alias color: fill.color
    property int radius

    Rectangle {
        id: border
        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: root.radius

        Rectangle {
            id: fill
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: root.borderWidth
            radius: root.radius * width / border.width / 2
        }
    }
}
```

This however does not allow me, to set the rectangle's color to 'transparent', which is sad, but I can live with it. Still I wonder, if there might be a more elegant way (besides using Context2D or  the QSG directly...)

Greetings,
-m-

Comment: `QQuickPaintedItem` would probably be easiest. There might be some ways to hack it with a `OpacityMask` shader effect, or to draw the gradient frame once in a `Canvas` then use the canvas as an image source similar to the approach explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025386/using-arbitrary-qml-items-as-cached-image-source

Comment: Wow, looks complicated. I will need quite some time to digest that. Thanks!

Comment: Though I try to avoid the use of QtGraphicalEffects, the OpacityMask is indeed quite powerful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion of ddriver from the comments, I put together a working sample of a rectangle, where you can set a gradient for the border, using the OpacityMask.
I heard somewhere, that the QtGraphicalEffects have bad performance, so I might try one without, in the future, but for whomever that is no concern, this is a working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    property Gradient borderGradient
    property int borderWidth: 0


    Loader {
        id: loader
        active: borderGradient
        anchors.fill: parent
        sourceComponent: border
    }

    Component.onCompleted: console.log(loader.active)

    Component {
        id: border
        Item {
            Rectangle {
                id: borderFill
                radius: root.radius
                anchors.fill: parent
                gradient: root.borderGradient
                visible: false
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: mask
                radius: root.radius
                border.width: root.borderWidth
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: 'transparent'
                visible: false   // otherwise a thin border might be seen.
            }

            OpacityMask {
                id: opM
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: borderFill
                maskSource: mask
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will only use the OpacityMask when needed (when a borderGradient is set), otherwise it behaves like a common rectangle.

I hope I might help someone, with this.