# Qt - QML Screen Mirroring in a dual monitor setup

Tags: qt, qml

I've developed an application, with the UI done using QML. What I was asked to do now is to make it so that when a second monitor is used, the second monitor shows everything that the program is doing. At first I thought of just telling the client to configure Windows to clone its screens. However when the applications uses some of its functionalities I need for the cloned screen to display certain indicators in the cloned screens but not on the original screen.

So my question is, How can I accomplish this. How can mirror what is happening in one screen, while maintaing enough control to draw in one and not in the other.

My only idea is to use a timer to take as screen shot at regular intervals and show that image in the second screen.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

Taking periodic screenshots, although perfectly doable, is undesired because of the impact to performance. Instead you should make use the main window's `onFrameSwapped()` signal, to grab images only when a new frame is generated.

Ideally, you'd want to make use of Layer or ShaderEffectSource, as suggested by [@dtech](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50867134/3833454), to read and re-render the frame straight from the GPU. Unfortunately, due to limitations in Qt Quick's Scene Graph, it is not possible to accomplish this across separate windows without destabilizing the source window's scene graph.

Update: Nevertheless, I've found a way to emulate the desired features of ShaderEffectSource using ShaderEffect instead. Your other options are to either copy frames through the CPU using Item's grabToImage function, or to re-implement QQuickView (your QML window) in C++ to grab images from the QML Engine when a new frame is generated.

### Working Solution 1: Use ShaderEffect (Update: New Solution)

The new approach I've found consists of using ShaderEffect on a child Window and forcing it to update by calling that Window's update() method, which is inherited from QWindow. By using ShaderEffect, you guarantee the source image will be accessed only through the GPU, increasing performance by orders of magnitude over solution #2.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow

    title: qsTr("Main Window")
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200
    color: "#0F0"

    Rectangle {
        id: viewport
        color: "#00F"
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height/2
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        // Draw QML Item into an off screen layer
        layer.enabled: true
        // Performance tweaks
        layer.smooth: false
        layer.mipmap: false
    }

    onFrameSwapped: {
        // Update mirror window manually with each new frame
        projectionWindow.update()
    }

    Window {
        id: projectionWindow

        property int screenID: 1

        transientParent: mainWindow
        visible: true
        x: Qt.application.screens[screenID].virtualX
        y: Qt.application.screens[screenID].virtualY
        width: Qt.application.screens[screenID].desktopAvailableWidth
        height: Qt.application.screens[screenID].desktopAvailableHeight
        flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
        color: "#000"
        visibility: Window.Maximized

        ShaderEffect {
            id: img

            // Set source to copy visuals from
            property variant source: viewport

            // Setting shader to the same resolution as the source may improve performance 
            width: viewport.width
            height: viewport.height

            // Performance tweak
            blending: false
        }
    }
}
```

Triggering update() manually has the side effect of preventing the child from updating on its own. Calling the update method on the source window from the child Window once whenever needed works around this limitation.

It is worth noting that this solution only works with Qt's basic renderer, which is single threaded. Qt prevents the texture from being accessed from a diferent rendering threads, giving the following error message and returning a null pointer:
`QQuickShaderEffectSource::textureProvider: can only be queried on the rendering thread of an exposed window`

The performance gained from this method is far greater than the performance loss of using the single threaded renderer. You can force use of the single threaded renderer by setting an environment variable at the start of your application. This can be done from inside the app by adding the following code at the very start of your main function:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WINDOWS)
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    putenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP=windows");
#else
    putenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP=basic");
#endif
#elif defined(Q_OS_MACOS) || defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
    setenv("QSG_RENDER_LOOP", "basic", 1);
#endif
```

Qt's documentation states that using the basic renderer reduces portability, but I can attest this approach works fine on Windows, macOS, and Linux and that it does not work on Haiku OS.

I've switched to this solution on the most recent versions of a project I develop. You can study the full implementation at:

- https://github.com/Cuperino/QPrompt/blob/072f0a7808f3a361cb93bca8961e884ac9d8bb56/src/kirigami_ui/PrompterPage.qml#L760
- https://github.com/Cuperino/QPrompt/blob/072f0a7808f3a361cb93bca8961e884ac9d8bb56/src/kirigami_ui/main.qml#L847
- https://github.com/Cuperino/QPrompt/blob/072f0a7808f3a361cb93bca8961e884ac9d8bb56/src/prompter/ProjectionsManager.qml#L261

### Working Solution 2: Use Item's grabToImage (original answer)

Another easy approach is to grab frames from QML, using an Item's [grabToImage()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) function. Since Window is not an item in itself, you'd have to grab the image from one of its elements. In this example, I grab the image from an item called viewport each time a frame is swapped on mainWindow, using the [onFrameSwapped()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#frameSwapped-signal) signal. Then the path to that image in memory is set as the source for the image in the second window, named projectionWindow. The second window will open on the screen set by the screenID variable; it is also set to be a frame-less window with its visibility is set to either Maximized or FullScreen, such that it is the only window seen on the second screen.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: mainWindow

    title: qsTr("Main Window")
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200
    color: "#0F0"

    Rectangle {
        id: viewport
        color: "#00F"
        width: parent.width/2
        height: parent.height/2
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }

    onFrameSwapped: {
        viewport.grabToImage(function(result) {
            projectionWindow.frame = String(result.url);
        });
    }

    Window {
        id: projectionWindow

        property int screenID: 1
        property alias frame: img.source

        transientParent: mainWindow
        visible: true
        x: Qt.application.screens[screenID].virtualX
        y: Qt.application.screens[screenID].virtualY
        width: Qt.application.screens[screenID].desktopAvailableWidth
        height: Qt.application.screens[screenID].desktopAvailableHeight
        flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
        color: "#000"
        visibility: Window.Maximized

        Image {
            id: img
            anchors.fill: parent
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            // Performance tweaks
            asynchronous: true
            cache: false
        }
    }
}
```

I used to employed this solution on a project I develop. You can study the full implementation at:

- https://github.com/Cuperino/QPrompt/blob/a873a2ec9b0619ec1bfdbde22fe90850e76969a5/src/kirigami_ui/main.qml#L828
- https://github.com/Cuperino/QPrompt/blob/a873a2ec9b0619ec1bfdbde22fe90850e76969a5/src/prompter/ProjectionsManager.qml#L260

### Alternate, incomplete, solution

The third, more manual, and unfinished solution consists of the following: You'd inherit from QQuickView or QQuickWindow, and then send the image to a second window on either the `QQuickWindow::afterRendering()` or the `QQuickWindow::frameSwapped()` signal. You would use a `QQuickFramebufferObject` or some other rendering pipeline such as DirectX, Metal or Vulkan, to render and grab the frame off screen. Using OpenGL as your renderer, means negating all the performance advantages that come from using the native rendering pipelines supported by Qt 6. You may need to implement the frame grab once per pipeline to get all performance benefits.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html

The following talk by Giuseppe D’Angelo shows how some of this is setup in Qt 5. It doesn't show how to copy the contents to another window/screen but it could aid in this regard.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_idc9BBRuI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-7fVGIBz6k

Answer (score 0):

You can [use particular QML elements as texture sources and easily duplicate them via trivial fragment shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025386/using-arbitrary-qml-items-as-cached-image-source).

You definitely do not want to take screenshots and draw that image back, it is wildly inefficient.

Keep in mind that it will be just a visual duplicate, it will not take user input. If you want it to be interactive in both windows, then you should simply use a single data object and connect it to two individual GUI elements.

OK, here is the code, but unfortunately, it evidently uncovers a bug in QML, as the implementation doesn't seem to work across different windows:

```
Window {
  id: mainw
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: qsTr("main window")

  Row {
    spacing: 5
    Rectangle {
      id: source
      width: 100
      height: 100
      color: ma.containsPress ? "red" : "cyan"
      Text {
        text: "adoy"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
      }
      MouseArea {
        id: ma
        anchors.fill: parent
      }
    }
    ShaderEffectSource {
      width: source.width
      height: source.height
      live: true
      sourceItem: source
    }
  }

  Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("another window")
    x: mainw.x + width + 10
    y: mainw.y
    Row {
      ShaderEffectSource {
        width: source.width
        height: source.height
        live: true
        sourceItem: source
      }
      Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "blue"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want (I mean NO user input). However I have no idea how to (or frankly what you are talking about) in your suggestions. I don't see how to do it from the link you gave me. Is there anywhere I can get a MWE? Like say do what I want with a simple window and a button or something?

Comment: Ok, I'll keep this in mind, but it doesn't work across different windows...

Comment: @aarelovich I filed a bug report, will see how this goes. Meanwhile you can pursue other directions.

Comment: @dtech, could you link to the bug report you filed? I'd like to monitor it and, perhaps, expand it with my findings.

Comment: @JavierCordero unfortunately, it was deemed too hard for them to fix: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68910?filter=-2

Comment: @dtech, That is unfortunate, but it makes perfect sense. The link you shared didn't load for me at first because of the filter. Here's the same link but without the filter: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68910

Comment: @JavierCordero they should have at least supported it if the display is on the same gpu, fail otherwise. That would be good enough in the vast majority of the cases. I am not expecting to share buffers between different adapters via pcie or something...

Comment: @dtech, I've found an alternative solution to this problem that achieves performance similar to using ShaderEffectSource, without Qt getting all glitchy. The solution is to enable layer for the item being captured, then use ShaderEffect to copy the contents over to the child window, and manually trigger update on said window, such that ShaderEffect updates like ShaderEffectSource would.